# Can the level sets of a function be the geodesics of a metric tensor field?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

Suppose we have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ whose graph is $(x, y, f(x,y))$. Let the parametric curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t),f(x(t),y(t)))$ be a level set (level curve) of $f$, that is $f(x(t),y(t)) = c$. Can we find a metric tensor field $g_{ij}$ defined on the graph of $f$ such that the curves $\gamma(t)$ are its geodesics?

From what I read in surface geometry (from Shifrin, Differential Geometry:
A First Course in Curves and Surfaces), I would say no, here is my reasoning: at a point $p$ on a geodesic, the curvature vector $\kappa\mathbf{N}$ only has a component along $\mathbf{n}$, the outward normal to the graph at $p$, where $\mathbf{N} = \gamma'(t)/\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert$ is the normal vector to the curve. Since a level curve is the intersection of the graph with a plane $z = c$, its normal vector  $\mathbf{N}$ is horizontal, and thus $\mathbf{n}$ would have to be horizontal for the curve to be geodesic. Since the surface is the graph of a function, this cannot happen, and thus a level curve on a graph cannot be a geodesic.

Do this explanation make sense? I don't have a strong background in differential geometry, so please let me know if I'm way off.
Thanks!

Comment: In your statement, you seem to allow the metric on the graph of $f$ to take *any* form, while in your argument you assume a particular metric induced by the embedding into Euclidean space. That said, I think the statement is still false due to issues which arise at critical points of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering about this while writing the question. Here is more context: I am an engineering student, trying to generate curved triangle meshes (for example for finite element methods) adapted to a function $f$. A standard practice for mesh adaptation is to define a metric tensor that reflects the error we commit by approximating $f$ by e.g. polynomials on each mesh triangle: the metric tensor will prescribe shortest distances where the error is more important, and vice versa. Does the geometric argument in my question only stand for the induced metric on the graph?

Comment: I think a reformulation of the question in my comment above is : What can we say about the geodesics of the metrics that are not the induced metric? Do they also have remarkable properties in terms of curvature, etc.? It sounds like a difficult question though.

Comment: The second sentence of the post makes no sense as written: The function $f$ has two variables, not three.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question.

Comment: @arthur To your first comment, the argument you give indeed only applies to the graph metric. To your second, "metrics that are not the induced metric" is far too broad to say anything specific about. As for metric "adapted to $f$" in the way you describe, these won't generally exist.

Comment: The question is still too sloppy: Each level curve has too many parameterizations: Are you asking for existence of a metric such that each level curve admits a geodesic parameterization? The answer will be negative: For instance, one can find functions such that some level curves are fractal, hence, cannot have geodesic parameterization. But maybe you want only some of the level curves to have geodesic parameterizations?

Comment: @Kajelad Could you please explain why the curvature argument only applies to the induced metric? I'm going over Shifrin's notes but I don't see where we make this hypothesis.

Comment: @arthur The covariant derivative is given by projecting on the tangent plane. That is the induced structure. To convince yourself, consider the flat metric on a torus. Any parallel will be a geodesic.

Comment: @arthur The fact that geodesics $\mathbf{n}$ is proportional to $\mathbf{N}$ is specific to embeddings with the induced metric. If you think of the problem in terms of abstract manifolds, neither of these vectors are even defined. If I'm reading your question correctly, it shouldn't involve any 3-dimensional spaces at all, since you're looking for an arbitrary metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (where the level curves of $f$ live); you can do this without trying to embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$.